# Using Vue 3 in IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I know there are a lot of threads covering Vue 2 support for IE11, which I know works fine with polyfills.
But is it possible to use Vue 3 in IE11? If not, is it planned to be supported?

I tried using Vue CLI `@vue/cli 4.5.8`, which currently installs `vue@3.0.2` (along with Vuex, Router and Typescript support). After using `transpileDependencies: ['vue-router']` in my vue.config.js I managed to get it working in Edge. IE11 kept complaining about the "vue" npm package. After transpiling it too I got `Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode` which I'm currently stuck with.

I've also tried babel polyfills and the other techniques mentioned for vue 2 without success.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Vue 3 is using JS [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for reactivity, which is not supported in **any version** of IE (see my link - scroll bottom)

"Compatibility" build (with same reactivity system as Vue 2 ...compatible with IE11) was promised in the past and it seems [it's coming "soon"](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1925) (even MS has announced IE end of support) but has no high priority atm I suppose...

`v3.0.0 One Piece` release notes:
*Migration and IE11 Support: We have pushed back the migration build (v3 build with v2 compatible behavior + migration warnings) and the IE11 build due to time constraints, and are aiming to focus on them in Q4 2020. Therefore, users planning to migrate an existing v2 app or require IE11 support should be aware of these limitations at this time.*

You can try some [ES6 Proxy pollyfils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-proxy-polyfill)  or just wait for Vue 3 compat build...

### UPDATE (2021/03/15)

In a recent [State of the Vuenion 2021 talk for Vue Amsterdam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=El8Jw2CFj7g&t=6818s) Evan You, the creator and lead developer of Vue, acknowledged that they are "rethinking legacy browser support"

Feel free to watch it yourself but what I take from it is that they see how much work is needed to bring up the rest of the ecosystem in-line with Vue 3 (Router/Vuex/Dev Tools/DX - dev experience) and they are in doubt (and I agree with that btw) the effort to make Vue 3 compatible with IE11 is worth it when we have Vue 2 perfectly working in IE 11 and IE 11 is practically dead for most of the users...

This comes in line with the effort to make a [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) for Vue 2 better and effort to create a guidance and documentation for library authors so they can create a Composition API libraries working in both Vue 2 and 3

This is tentative and will not be decided without public discussion and feedback from community. So if you are interested, there should be a new RFC soon ready for your feedback in [Vue RFCs repo](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs)

### UPDATE (2021/04/08)

RFC is now [posted and open for discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/294)

### TLDR

[There will not be a version of Vue 3 for IE 11](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0038-vue3-ie11-support.md). If you need to support IE 11, use Vue 2....

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to keep this up to date. 

Comment: Does this mean that Vue is a no-go for any organization that has to support IE11? It looks like LTS for Vue 2 is [only 18 months](https://github.com/vuejs/roadmap#release-channels-and-lts) after Vue 3 if fully released.

Comment: @RayT 18 months of LTS is ok considering IE11 will be out of support in [about 7 months](https://death-to-ie11.com/)

Comment: Sadly in many industries - mine being medical related - organisations and software vendors are EXTREMELY slow in changing their software. So just because MS drops support such vendors will not follow suit and that means our applications cannot drop support either. It's June 2022 and I expect Vue 4 will be out before we can 'move' to Vue 3 :(