# IE11 Error: SCRIPT1006 - Expected ')' with vue app

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, babeljs

I am having difficulties telling vue to polyfill my application in a way that it runs on IE11.
If I understand everything correctly, I have to tell my `npm build` to insert *core-js* and *regenerator-runtime* for my generator functions.

The app works fine on Chrome/Firefox, but I persistently get the error `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'` on IE11.

Can someone point me in a direction to solve this?

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "vue-form",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 10"
  ]
}
```

my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry"
    }]
  ],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-parameters', '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
}
```

and my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    // options ...
    publicPath: './',
    transpileDependencies: ['bootstrap', 'vuetify']
}
```

Does anybody have any clue on how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: If you want the app to run in IE 11, you need to use Vue 2.x - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64836337/381282

Comment: did you try to import `import '@babel/polyfill'` at the starting of the `min.js` file? if not, try to import it. Then again try to run the project and see whether it run in IE.