# Vue.js website is blank in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11

**Package.json**

```
{
“name”: “Chatwidget”,
“version”: “0.1.0”,
“private”: true,
“scripts”: {
“serve”: “vue-cli-service serve”,
“build”: “vue-cli-service build”,
“lint”: “vue-cli-service lint”,
“deploy”: “rsync -aczv dist/ kuncom@kunden.comspace.de:/home/kunden.comspace.de/pages/mememru/”
},
“dependencies”: {
“date-fns”: “^1.30.1”,
“debounce”: “^1.2.0”,
“leaflet”: “^1.4.0”,
“leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility”: “^0.1.1”,
“loglevel”: “^1.6.1”,
“marked”: “^1.1.1”,
“node-fetch”: “^2.3.0”,
“sanitize-html”: “^2.3.2”,
“url-search-params-polyfill”: “^5.1.0”,
“uuid”: “^3.3.2”,
“v-emoji-picker”: “^2.3.1”,
“vue”: “^2.5.21”,
“whatwg-fetch”: “^3.0.0”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“@vue/cli-plugin-babel”: “^3.3.0”,
“@vue/cli-plugin-eslint”: “^3.3.0”,
“@vue/cli-service”: “^4.5.8”,
“babel-eslint”: “^10.0.1”,
“eslint”: “^5.12.0”,
“eslint-plugin-vue”: “^5.1.0”,
“node-sass”: “^4.11.0”,
“sass-loader”: “^7.1.0”,
“vue-template-compiler”: “^2.5.21”
},
“eslintConfig”: {
“root”: true,
“env”: {
“node”: true,
“jquery”: true
},
“extends”: [
“plugin:vue/essential”,
“eslint:recommended”
],
“rules”: {},
“parserOptions”: {
“parser”: “babel-eslint”
}
},
“postcss”: {
“plugins”: {
“autoprefixer”: {}
}
},
“browserslist”: [
“> 1%”,
“last 2 versions”,
“not ie <= 8”
]
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
const conf = {
    publicPath: './',
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            // pass options to sass-loader
            sass: {
                // @/ is an alias to src/
                data: `@import "@/global/css/style.scss";`
            }
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {},
    productionSourceMap: false,
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    conf.filenameHashing = false;
    conf.configureWebpack.optimization = {
        splitChunks: false
    };
}

module.exports = conf;
```

When i execute *npm run serve* i get following error

```
eval("var rng = __webpack_require__(/*! ./lib/rng */ \"./node_modules/uuid/lib/rng-browser.js\");\nvar bytesToUuid = __webpack_require__(/*! ./lib/bytesToUuid */ \"./node_modules/uuid/lib/bytesToUuid.js\");\n\nfunction v4(options, buf, offset) {\n  var i = buf && offset || 0;\n\n  if (typeof(options) == 'string') {\n    buf = options === 'binary' ? new Array(16) : null;\n    options = null;\n  }\n  options = options || {};\n\n  var rnds = options.random || (options.rng || rng)();\n\n  // Per 4.4, set bits for version and `clock_seq_hi_and_reserved`\n  rnds[6] = (rnds[6] & 0x0f) | 0x40;\n  rnds[8] = (rnds[8] & 0x3f) | 0x80;\n\n  // Copy bytes to buffer, if provided\n  if (buf) {\n    for (var ii = 0; ii < 16; ++ii) {\n      buf[i + ii] = rnds[ii];\n    }\n  }\n\n  return buf || bytesToUuid(rnds);\n}\n\nmodule.exports = v4;\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./node_modules/uuid/v4.js\n");
```

I added following stuff in my **vue.config.js**
The stuff in configureWebpack: {} for debugging and
transpileDependencies:[] to transpile all dependencies to older Ecmascript Syntax to get my Website running in Internet Explorer 11.

```
configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all',
          maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
          minSize: 0,
          cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name(module) {
              // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
              // or node_modules/packageName
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
    productionSourceMap: false,
    transpileDependencies: ['date-fns','debounce','leaflet','leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility',
    'loglevel','marked','node-fetch','sanitize-html','url-search-params-polyfill','uuid','v-emoji-picker','vue','whatwg-fetch','escape-string-regexp'
    ],
```

But unfortunately it didnt help.

On *npm run serve* i get following Error in Internet Explorer 11:

```
npm.escape-string-regexp.js (11,1)
```

On *npm run build* i get following Error if i start Index.html in Internet Explorer 11:

```
identifier expected: (function(e){let{existsSync:r,readFileSync:i}=n(3),{dirname:o,join:s}=n(“df7c”),a=n(“dc74”);function c(t){return e?e.from(t,“base64”).toString():window.atob(t)}class u
```

```
Chatwidget is undefined in Index.html: window.addEventListener(‘DOMContentLoaded’, function(){
Chatwidget.initChatWidget(document.getElementById(‘chatwidget’), ChatwidgetConfig, ChatwidgetUser);
```

Comment: The main reason why your Vue app is breaking in IE11 is because the browser does not support modern JavaScript syntax. ... The Internet Explorer browser was deprecated in favour of Microsoft's more modern Edge browser. for more info reffer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881807/compiling-es6-and-vue-js-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: @Bhumit070 , thx for your answer but this was clear for me from the start. I know that my app is running in Chrome, Edge and other browsers. I like to get a solution for missing IE 11 compatibility. According to Vue.js site there shouldnt be  a problem with IE 11 browser.

Comment: hey you might need to tinker your vue configs and the link that i have mention is asnwer of yours

Comment: See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you supporting IE11? It is a browser that has been discontinued and Microsoft said will no longer support IE11 on MS products from August. All of that despite the fact that it has less than 1% of the browser market share. I don't know your reasons but I'd really rethink if is really worth spending time on this issue, plus you're building a modern app. Its like putting a Ferrari engine on a Vauxhall corsa

Comment: @ gugateider , its not me who wants to support it but my company. ^^ Believe me, its not fun for me to search for solutions to get everything working in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, i will have a look at browserlist settings but i think i should have already the right settings

Comment: Try adding `targets:{browsers:["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]}` as parameter to your preset in `babel.config.js`, and `stage-2` as a second preset. You should also add `core-js` as a devDependency.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, i added core-js@3.9.0 as dev dependency and added targets to babel.config.js and added targets to babel.config.js {
  presets: [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        // The % refers to the global coverage of users from browserslist
        "browsers": [ "> 1%","last 2 versions","not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "vue"
  ]
}  but still the same eval error if i execute npm run serve or  "identifier expected"  for app.js line "(0,e.length-t.length)),e&&(this.hostname=e)}},"0b71":function(e,t,n){"use strict";(function(t){let{existsSync:i,readFileSync:r}=n(3),"

Comment: @Bhumit070, i tried your solution but unfortunately it didnt worked

Comment: Seems like Babel does not get right browserslist - it spills out ES6 features (e.g. `let` keyword and object destructuring). It is hard to tell why ...

Comment: First, I suggest you try to run the empty vue.js app in the IE 11 browser. After it works, you can try to add the dependencies and relevant code step by step and check the app by running after each change. Just for testing purposes, try to add your dependencies to the `module.exports`. For example: `module.exports = { transpileDependencies: [ 'vue-echarts', 'resize-detector', 'muse-ui' ] }`. See whether it makes any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all. My problem was solved. Problem for Internet Explorer is the **“sanitize-html”: “^2.3.2”** and **"emoji-picker”: “^2.3.1”** . Both dependencies arent compatible with IE 11. Solution: Build 2 versions: 1 for IE and 1 for modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that some dependency of yours is using ES6 syntax.

> By default `babel-loader` ignores all files inside `node_modules`. If you want to explicitly transpile a dependency with Babel, you can list it in this option

[transpileDependencies](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies)

You need to find out which one it is and add it to `transpileDependencies` - `vue.config.js`

**Also** the error message is very strange - `function(e){let{existsSync:r,readFileSync:i}` - both `existsSync` and `readFileSync` look like Node API. So check you don't use any Node package for browser app (for example `node-fetch` is definitely Node only lib and will not work inside the browser)

Comment: Michal Levy, thanks for your help. The first tip is what i did already. I added all dependencies which i use in transpileDependencies. But the same error occurs. For the second tip of you:  My app works in other browsers such as Chrome, Edge, Mozilla Firefox and only does not work in Internet Explorer 11. So i think the dependencies i use must be valid for browsers. Or what do you think?    I got some new information. I tried to create new vue3.js projects and receive an error from  beginning. Is there a possibility that vue3.js is incompatible with IE 11 and how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Same error or different one? Yes, Vue 3 is not compatible with IE 11 [yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836337/using-vue-3-in-ie11/64837153#64837153) so just stay on v 2.x. Didn't mention this in my answer because you `package.json` is using v2

Comment: Michal Levy, yes its my fault. I should have said that i startet with vue3.js and tried unsuccessful to migrate it to vue2.js but its still not working with my latest vue2.js configuration as you see above.

Comment: Michal Levy, so to sum it up. My first configuration was for vue.js 3 and then i tried to migrate it down to vue2.js because i found hints that vue3.js is incompatible as you mentioned now. But still nothing is working and i am trying to figure out why.