# In a Vue CLI app, how can I find which dependency causes a syntax error in IE11?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli

In a Vue.js 3 project, I'm getting the following error in Internet Explorer 11:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
> File: chunk-vendors.js, Line: 2712, Column: 1

This is apparently due to one (or more) of my dependencies using syntax that IE11 does not support, and they are not getting transpiled / polyfilled by Babel. If I read it correctly, dependencies in node_modules are excluded from transpilation by default (this default being set by Vue CLI). Now there is at least one that I need to manually include as a target, but I don't know how to find out which one.

My current idea is to identify the dependencies that need to be transpiled / polyfilled and add them as [`transpileDependencies`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies), but to do that I need to figure out what the problematic dependencies are.

The error points to *"chunk-vendors.js, Line: 2712, Column: 1"*, which starts like this:

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n
/* harmony export (binding) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"compile\", function() { return compile; });\n
/* harmony import */
var _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(
/*! @vue/runtime-dom */
\"./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js\");\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"customRef\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"customRef\"]; });\n\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"isProxy\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"isProxy\"]; });\n\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"isReactive\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"isReactive\"]; });\n\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"isReadonly\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"isReadonly\"]; });\n\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"isRef\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"isRef\"]; });\n\n
/* harmony reexport (safe) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"markRaw\", function() {
return _vue_runtime_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"markRaw\"]; });
```

and goes on for much longer. I can't see anything that stands out as a suspect.

How do I know which dependency is causing the error?

Do I have to use [useBuiltIns: 'entry'](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#usebuiltins-usage) and just add every possible polyfill?

---

**Update:** as one of the commenters has pointed out, I currently have no hope of supporting IE11 with Vue 3. But the basic question still stands, and I have found a [very useful answer here](https://jacklyons.me/how-to-fix-vuejs-not-working-in-ie11/). This article describes how to split dependencies into chunks that can then be addressed individually, rather than getting a syntax error for the whole thing.

Comment: What about source maps? When I face issue like this and I'm unable to find root cause, there is always brute force binary search aproach. Transpile half of dependencies, if it doesn't fix it, second one and so on.. Often its faster than "proper" solution which usually requires some digging..

Comment: To find it, turn on source maps, turn off tree shaking, turn off chunking, but it's probably easier to just have a separate IE task that runs babel on the final bundle as well, turning it into IE11-safe code. and then have your server respond with that bundle instead of the "real" one for request by IE11 user agents. (but really, turn off IE11 because not even MS wants you to use it anymore, they just can't legally remove support for it without being on the hook for hundreds of millions of dollars in enterprise claims =)

Comment: Don't know about your dependencies but from the 1st lines it is clear you are using Vue 3 [which currently does not work in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837153/381282)

Comment: @michal-levý: I was not aware of that, thank you. Your comment may not have solved my problem, but it moved it into a much more urgent category. We will most likely be reverting to Vue 2.

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans: I don't think an developer would choose to support IE at this point. I fought hard against it and lost. If your most valuable clients insist on that browser, you will have to support it. It's a shame, but it is what it is.